# SetFocus is placing focus on incorrect textbox

Tags: vba, textbox, setfocus

When I check the value of the user's input and the user did not input a valid response, I set focus back to that textbox.  However, that is not happening.  Instead, it is advancing to the next textbox.

CODE:

```
Private Sub tbxStartTime_AfterUpdate() 
  Dim ckTime As Date 
  On Error Resume Next 
  ckTime = DateValue(tbxStartTime.Value) 
  MsgBox ckTime 

  tbxStartTime.Text = Format(dTime, "h:mm am/pm") 

  If tbxStartTime.Value = "" Or Not IsDate(tbxStartTime.Text) Or Not tbxStartTime = Format(tbxStartTime.Value, "h:mm am/pm") Then 
     MsgBox "Please enter the Time in the correct format" 
     tbxStartTime = "" 
     tbxStartTime.SetFocus 
     Exit Sub 
  End If 

End Sub
```

Textbox indicated in red is the one I am checking with above code.
It is tbxStartTime.  However, the focus is put on the textbox below it, tbxClassHours

[image: Screenshot of textbox I am checking.]

As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct for what I want to happen.

Comment: Did you get a MsgBox and then incorrect focus?  If you did not get a MsgBox then the If statement did not evaluate to True.

Comment: Welcome Les! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Is this `ms-access` or `excel` ? Please add a tag for the correct product.

Comment: Use BeforeUpdate event to validate code. Or use ValidationRule and ValidationText properties.